# Jquery, To check if we get any new messages, in chat app using php, mysql, jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a chat app in my existing app.
I am using PHP and Mysql to handle backend and for the frontend, I am using Jquery.

This is html code where I am displaying the messages after clicking on user suppose user id from is 50 and user id to is 1.

```
<div class="content">
      <!-- MESSAGE CONTENT -->
      <div id="msgbox" class="popup-messages"></div>

      <!-- BUTTON AND TETX INPUT -->
      <div style="width:100%;display:table;position:fixed;bottom:0px">
        <div style="width:90%;display:table-cell">
          <input type="text" id="sentmessagetext" class="inputform form-control"  placeholder="Type your message here">
        </div>
        <div style="width:10%;display:table-cell;">
          <a id="sendBtn'+ id +'"  onclick="sendMsg('<?= $id ?>','<?= $fromid ?>')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >
            <i style="font-size:20px;margin-top:-2px;" class="fas fa-arrow-right text-white"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS code to fetch user

```
         <script>
            $(function(){
              register_popup('<?= $_GET["uid"] ?>', '<?= $_GET["fromid"] ?>');
            });
          function register_popup(id,fromuser)
          {

             $.post('includes/get_user_by_id.php',{ id:id }).done(function(data){

                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(json.status == '1'){
                  $('#totalname').html(json.data[0].firstname+'  '+json.data[0].lastname);

                  fetch_msg(fromuser, id);

                   $('#sentmessagetext').keypress(function (e) {
                      if (e.which == 13) {
                        sendMsg(id, fromuser);
                        return false;
                      }
                    });
                  console.log(json.data);
                }
             });
          }
            function check_if_empty(id){

              var textfield = $("#sentmessagetext").val();

              if(textfield.length > 0){
                  $('#sendBtn').removeClass('disabled');
                  console.log(textfield.length);
              }else{
                    $('#sendBtn').addClass('disabled');
              }

            }


            function fetch_msg(from, to){
              $('#msgbox').html(' ');
              var new_messages = "";
              setInterval(function(){

              $.post('includes/fetch_msg.php',{toid:to,fromid:from}).done(function(data){
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(json.status == '1'){
                  for(var i = json.data.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
                    if(json.data[i].from_user == from){
                      new_messages = new_messages+ '<div class="chatmsgto">'+json.data[i].msg+'<br><i><span style="font-size:9px;float:right">'+json.data[i].sent_on+'</span></i></div>';
                    } else {
                      new_messages = new_messages+ '<div class="chatmsgfrom">'+json.data[i].msg+'<br><i><span style="font-size:9px;float:right">'+json.data[i].sent_on+'</span></i></div>';
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
            },1000);

//AFTER THIS NOt WORKING
              setInterval(function(){
            var old_messages = $('#msgbox').html(); // check for old msg

            if(new_messages != old_messages){ //check
              $('#msgbox').html(new_messages);//show
              $('#msgbox').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msgbox').prop("scrollHeight")}, 0);
            }
            },2000);
            }
            //
            function sendMsg(touser,fromuser){
              // alert(touser);
              var msgtext = $('#sentmessagetext').val();
                  if(msgtext.length > 0){
                  $.post('includes/send_chat_messages.php',{ to:touser, msg:msgtext }).done(function(data){
                    if(data == '1'){
                      $('#sentmessagetext').val(' ');
                      // $("#msgbox"+touser).load(location.href + " #msgbox"+touser);
                      fetch_msg(fromuser, touser);
                    }
                  });
                }else{
                  alert('Enter text to send');
                }

              }
    </script>
```

I am getting the messages one by one but they keep on refreshing and adding new messages every time and scroll to bottom is not working.
I want to refresh the result only when new messages are entered.

Comment: Your `<?= $_GET["uid"] ?>` is open to XSS injections.

Comment: Thanks but apart from that can you solve this.

Comment: Not sure, is there a JS error or you are just retrieving all messages currently and want to only retrieve new ones? I think updating `fetch_msg.php` so it can take in an `id` and then you only retrieve records `>` that value might resolve the issue